# sorted() only sorting by first digit

Tags: python

i need to sort the first column of a table. it looks something like

```
6000 799 
7000 352
8000 345
9000 234
10000 45536 
11000 3436
1000 342
2000 123
3000 1235
4000 234
5000 233
```

i want the first column to be in ascending order, but it is sorting it by only the first digit, not the value of the whole column, i.e.

```
1000 342
10000 45536
11000 3436
2000 123
```

But i want

```
1000 342
2000 123
3000 1235
etc
```

Currently trying:

```
SortInputfile=open("InterpBerg1","r")
line=SortInputfile.readlines()
line.sort()
map(SortOutputfile.write, line)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sort` and `sorted` function support a key argument which allows you to specify the key which should be used to perform the sorting. Since you want a numerical sort order and no alphabetical sort order you need to extract the first column and convert it to an int:

```
SortInputfile=open("InterpBerg1","r")
line=SortInputfile.readlines()
line.sort(key=lambda line: int(line.split()[0]))
map(SortOutputfile.write, line)
```

A cleaner version of this could would be:

```
# read input file
with open(input_filename) as fh:
    lines = fh.readlines()

# sort lines
lines.sort(key=lambda line: int(line.split()[0]))

# write output file
with open(output_filename, 'w') as fh:
    fh.writelines(lines)
```

Answer (score 2):

For numeric order, you should convert the strings to numbers. To do it on the fly, use the `key` parameter:

```
outfile.writelines(sorted(
    open('InterpBerg1'),
    key = lambda l: int(l.split(maxsplit=1)[0])))
```

Edit: I agree with others suggesting to use `with` statements when working with files, so:

```
with open('Output', 'w') as outfile, open('InterpBerg1') as infile:
    outfile.writelines(sorted(infile,
        key = lambda l: int(l.split(maxsplit=1)[0])))
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should know that there are two standard ways to sort a list in Python. The first is `sorted()`, which is a generic built-in function that takes a list and returns a sorted *copy* of the list, and the second is `.sort()`, which is a built-in *method* for lists that sorts this list *in-place* (and returns `None`). You are using `.sort()`; there is no `.sorted()`.

Second, the items in your list are not integers; they are strings. You can tell this from the fact that you created the list using `readlines()`, which returns an array of strings. When you sort strings, they are by default sorted alphabetically. This is why they appear to be sorted by "first digit only" in your example.

In order to sort by something else, you have two options, both of which are expressed as keyword parameters to the `sorted()` function and `.sort()` method. The first, as mentioned in a couple other answers already, is the `key` parameter, which defines, roughly speaking, what quality or attribute of a list item you want to use to sort by; in your case, you want to use *the value of the first number*. You can get this by splitting the string by whitespace, taking the first token, and converting to an int. (Lev Levitsky's and bikeshedder's answers both show appropriate ways to do this). The value passed to `key` must be a function (either a standard function or a lambda function) that takes as input the list item and returns the desired value. The other parameter you could use is the `cmp` parameter, which is a function that takes as input two list items (or their keys, if you also define the `key` parameter) and returns a value indicating which item is "greater." This is a slightly more complicated feature to use, but it adds somewhat more flexibility to your sorting.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, was getting pretty confused between the two!

Answer (score 0):

same as the other answers - just a couple of minutes behind, and IMO a little more readable.

```
lines = []

with open("InterpBerg1","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        lines.append(tuple(int(i) for i in line.split()[:]))

print sorted(lines)
```