# Sort a list on the basis of first digit of the elements

Tags: python-3.x

Here is what I want

```
lis = [55,57,7,48,73,5]
```

After sorting on the basis of first digit in descending order

```
lis = [73,7,57,55,5,48]
```

This is what I tried but it only returns complete numbers in decreasing order

```
lis.sort(reverse=True)
lis = [73,57,55,48,7,5]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sorted() only sorting by first digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591435/sorted-only-sorting-by-first-digit)

Comment: @VictorC. I am not using a file and my elements are integers.Besides I am looking for a pythonic way to do this real quick rather than extracting first digit of every number and performing operations.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36949481/sort-list-of-ints-by-the-first-digit-of-each-int

My answer below is basically copied from that answer I linked above in each comment, but changing only the variable name. The part of the answers that matter should answer your question. In fact, this is the fastest way to sort the lists by the first digit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll adapt the answer in the question I linked, since that solution involves reading from a file (though the answer is extremely similar). The `sort()` function accepts a parameter called `key` that indicates a function to use when sorting the list.

```
lis.sort(key=lambda x: int(str(x)[0]))
```

In the above function, `int(str(x)[0])` converts each element into a string, takes the first character (which would be the first digit), and converts that back into an integer. Python then sorts the numbers based on that first digit.

Answer (score 1):

**THAT SORTING HAPPENS WITH STRINGS**

If you were to sort an int list e.g:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 20, 22, 30]
print(sorted(a))

>>>
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 20, 22, 30]
```

Now if you were to sort that same list, but each element is a string object:

```
a = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '10', '11', '12', '13', '20', '22', '30']
print(sorted(a))

>>>
['1', '10', '11', '12', '13', '2', '20', '22', '3', '30', '4', '5']
```